# What flower is this from?

Tags: flowers, seeds

New gardener here: This flower has gone to seed but I don't know what kind of flower it is. Any ideas? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Would be easier with a picture of when it was in flower, and the leaves.

Comment: Sorry! I don't have any photos from then...

Comment: Where in the world (approximately) are you located? Did you find this seedhead in a garden or in the wild?

Comment: Sage or savory? Plant now and be surprised in Spring.

Comment: I am on Vancouver Island, off the west coast of Canada. About zone 7, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I think its one of the *Phacelia* varieties - depending where you are in the world, the variety might be *Phacelia cicutaria*, the seed head of which most resembles those in your image. There is a good photo showing the seed head on Flickr, titled Seed Head of Caterpillar Phacelia, its common name, but I can't find a way to link to it.

Comment: Thanks Bamboo! I don't recognize it, but I suspect that I missed it in spring. I think it came from a pack of mixed seeds.... I will plant it and see what comes up!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!
I planted the seeds and saw the fern-like leaves growing.... Fernleaf fiddleneck Phacelia tanacetifolia  :-)
thanks all!
[image]